# Blank report when using downloadHandler in a shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to setup a download button in an interactive R shiny document for users. The R shiny document runs fine, but the download button fails when I attempt to save the downloaded file somewhere. 
The idea is to download all the inputs and outputs, I am using the downloadHandler code:

I have spent sometime trying to debug this and I have not quite figured out what I am possibly missing.
I am new to R shiny web applications and I hope this is enough information to help find a solution to my problem

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(pander)
library(tibble)


ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(
                title = "",
                titleWidth = 1000),
        dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Camada 1", tabName = "camada1", icon = icon("th")),
                        menuItem("Camada 2", tabName = "camada2", icon = icon("th")),
                        menuItem("Parâmetros Calculados", tabName = "parcalc", icon = icon("th")),
                        br(),
                        br()
                )
        ),
        hr(),
        radioButtons("format", "Download report:", c("PDF", "Word"),
                     inline = TRUE
        ),
        #checkboxInput("echo", "Show code in report?", FALSE),
        downloadButton("downloadReport"),
        hr()
)

dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
                #Camada 1 tab content
                tabItem(tabName = "camada1",
                        fluidRow(
                                box(
                                        title = "",
                                        tags$b(""),
                                        tags$b(":"),
                                        textInput("x1", "", value = "7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13"
                                        ),
                                        textInput("y1", "", value = "225, 235, 237, 239, 245, 255"
                                        ),
                                        hr(),
                                        tags$b("Plot:"),
                                        textInput("xlab", label = "Título do eixo x:", value = "", placeholder = "xlabel"),
                                        textInput("ylab", label = "Título do eixo y:", value = "", placeholder = "ylabel"),
                                        checkboxInput("se", "Inserir intervalo de confiança na regressão?", FALSE)
                                ),
                                box(
                                        tags$b("Seus Dados:"),
                                        DT::dataTableOutput("tbl1"),
                                        br(),
                                        uiOutput("data1"),
                                        br(),
                                        plotOutput("plot1", height = 500)

                                )
                        )),
                tabItem(tabName = "camada2",
                        fluidRow(
                                box(
                                        title = "",
                                        textInput("f12", "", value = "11, 11.5, 11.7, 11.9, 12, 12.5"
                                        ),
                                        textInput("x2", "", value = "15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20"
                                        ),
                                        textInput("y2", "", value = "330, 335, 337, 342, 345, 350"
                                        ),
                                        tags$b("Plot2:"),
                                        textInput("xlab2", label = "Título do eixo x:", value = "", placeholder = "xlabel"),
                                        textInput("ylab2", label = "Título do eixo y:", value = "", placeholder = "ylabel"),
                                        checkboxInput("se2", "Inserir intervalo de confiança na regressão?", FALSE)

                                ),
                                box(
                                        DT::dataTableOutput("tbl2"),
                                        br(),
                                        uiOutput("data2"),
                                        br(),
                                        plotOutput("plot2", height = 500)

                                )
                        )),
                tabItem(tabName = "parcalc",
                        fluidRow(
                                box(
                                        tags$b("Camada 1"),
                                        verbatimTextOutput("summary1")
                                ),
                                box(
                                        tags$b("Camada 2"),
                                        verbatimTextOutput("summary2")
                                )

                        ))

        )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
        extract <- function(text){
                text <- gsub(" ", " ", text)
                split <- strsplit(text, ",", fixed = FALSE)[[1]]
                as.numeric(split)
        }

        #data output 1
        output$tbl1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
                y1 <- extract(input$y1)
                x1 <- extract(input$x1)
                yval1 <- extract(input$yval1)
                xval1 <- extract(input$xval1)
                DT::datatable(data.frame(x1, y1, xval1, yval1),
                              extensions = "Buttons",
                              options = list(
                                      lengthChange = FALSE,
                                      dom = "Blfrtip",
                                      buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print")
                              ))
        })

        output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                y1 <- extract(input$y1)
                x1 <- extract(input$x1)
                yval1 <- extract(input$yval1)
                xval1 <- extract(input$xval1)
                #dat <- as.data.frame(x,y)
                fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
                newx1 <- seq(min(x1), max(x1),by = 0.05)
                conf_interval1 <- predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(x1 = newx1), 
                                          interval="confidence",
                                          level = 0.95)
                yvalid <- round(predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(x1 = xval1)),2)
                mse_train <- mean(fit1$residuals^2) 
                mse_val <- mean((yval1 - yvalid)^2)
                plot(x1, y1, pch = 19, col = "black", cex = 1.5, 
                     xlab = input$xlab, 
                     ylab = input$ylab)
                abline(fit1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
                points(xval1, yval1, pch = 19, col = "blue", cex = 1.5)
                points(xval1, yvalid, col = "salmon", cex = 2)
                legend("topleft", inset = 0.05, legend = c("Pontos Exp.", "fit", "Val. Exp.", "Val. Calc."),
                       col = c("black", "red", "blue", "salmon"), lty=1:2, cex=1) 
                if(input$se == TRUE){
                        lines(newx1, conf_interval1[,2], col="blue", lty=2)
                        lines(newx1, conf_interval1[,3], col="blue", lty=2)
                        legend("topleft", inset = 0.05, legend = c("Pontos Exp.", "fit", "Val. Exp.","Val. Calc.", "C.I 95%"),
                               col = c("black", "red", "blue", "salmon", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=1)                       
                }
        })

        output$data1 <- renderUI({
                y1 <- extract(input$y1)
                x1 <- extract(input$x1)
                if(anyNA(x1) | length(x1) < 2 | anyNA(y1) | length(y1) < 2) {
                        "Entrada Inválida ou quantidade de dados insuficiente"
                } else if (length (x1) != length (y1)){
                        "NÃºmero de dados de x deve ser igual ao número de dados de y"
                } else {
                        withMathJax(
                                paste0("\\(\\bar{x} = \\) ", round(mean(x1), 3)),
                                br(),
                                paste0("\\(\\bar{y} = \\) ", round(mean(y1), 3)),
                                br(),
                                paste0("\\(n = \\) ", length(x1))
                        )
                }
        })
        output$summary1 <- renderPrint({
                y1 <- as.numeric(extract(input$y1))
                x1 <- as.numeric(extract(input$x1))
                fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
                summary(fit1)
        })

        #data output Camada 2
        output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
                y2 <- extract(input$y2)
                x2 <- extract(input$x2)
                #fit da camada 1 para camada 2
                y1 <- extract(input$y1)
                x1 <- extract(input$x1)
                fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
                f12 <- extract(input$f12)
                p12 <- round(predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(x1 = f12)),2)
                pcam2 <- y2 - p12
                DT::datatable(data.frame(f12, p12, x2, y2, pcam2),
                              extensions = "Buttons",
                              options = list(
                                      lengthChange = FALSE,
                                      dom = "Blfrtip",
                                      buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print")
                              ))
        })
        output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
                p2 <- extract(input$y2)
                x2 <- extract(input$x2)
                #dat <- as.data.frame(x,y)
                y1 <- extract(input$y1)
                x1 <- extract(input$x1)
                fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
                f12 <- extract(input$f12)
                p12 <- round(predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(x1 = f12)),2)
                y2 <- as.numeric(p2) - as.numeric(p12)
                fit2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2)
                newx2 = seq(min(x2),max(x2),by = 0.05)
                conf_interval2 <- predict(fit2, newdata=data.frame(x2 = newx2), 
                                          interval="confidence",
                                          level = 0.95)
                plot(x2, y2, pch = 1,  
                     xlab = input$xlab2, 
                     ylab = input$ylab2)

        })

})

        output$data2 <- renderUI({
                y2 <- extract(input$y2)
                x2 <- extract(input$x2)
                if(anyNA(x2) | length(x2) < 2 | anyNA(y2) | length(y2) < 2) {
                        "Entrada Inválida ou quantidade de dados insuficiente"
                } else if (length (x2) != length (y2)){
                        "Numero de dados de x deve ser igual ao número de dados de y"
                } else {
                        withMathJax(
                                paste0("\\(\\bar{x} = \\) ", round(mean(x2), 3)),
                                br(),
                                paste0("\\(\\bar{y} = \\) ", round(mean(y2), 3)),
                                br(),
                                paste0("\\(n = \\) ", length(x2))
                        )
                }
        })
        output$summary2 <- renderPrint({
                p2 <- as.numeric(extract(input$y2))
                x2 <- as.numeric(extract(input$x2))
                #dat <- as.data.frame(x,y)
                y1 <- extract(input$y1)
                x1 <- extract(input$x1)
                fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
                f12 <- extract(input$f12)
                p12 <- round(predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(x1 = f12)),2)
                y2 <- as.numeric(p2) - as.numeric(p12)
                fit2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2)
                summary(fit2)
        })
        })
})

output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
                paste0("my-report", sep = ".", switch(
                        input$format, PDF = "pdf", Word = "docx"
                ))
        },

        content = function(file) {
                src <- normalizePath("report.Rmd")

                # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
                # permission to the current working directory
                owd <- setwd(tempdir())
                on.exit(setwd(owd))
                file.copy(src, "report.Rmd", overwrite = TRUE)


                library(rmarkdown)
                out <- render("report.Rmd", switch(
                        input$format,
                        PDF = pdf_document(), Word = word_document()
                ))
                file.rename(out, file)
        }
)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This could be due to an antivirus on your computer.

Comment: But if I try a different code such as https://www.statsandr.com/blog/a-shiny-app-for-simple-linear-regression-by-hand-and-in-r/ it works

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to solve this issue.